# Can't genrate RSA private key with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Tags: openssl, api-platform.com, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm using this library and following it's [documentation](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md). In the "Generate the SSH keys" section it's mentioned that I must execute these commands:

```sh
mkdir -p config/jwt
openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout
```

I try to execute this command:

```sh
openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096
```

but when it asks me to enter the pass phrase, I can't type anything (so the next one cant be executed).
I tried to type it in the Windows terminal, in VS Code terminal, and even in git bash, but it's still not working.

Is it a known issue? If so, is there a solution?

I want to note that on git bash it is still blocked in +++++++ and it doesn't ask for a pass phrase.

I'm on Windows 10, Symfony 4.4.15, API Platform 2.5. OpenSSL command is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behaviour related to [security](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268006/why-is-the-password-i-entered-not-visible). Simply input phrase and press `Enter`.

Comment: I understood that it's needed that i put the phrase pass, but as i explained before, i can't type anything, that's the pb